# map data different from Google map

Tags: ipad, google-maps, ios4, mapkit

I am using MapKit framework to display maps in my app. Eventually, I found the map being displayed is different from google map or the offical maps app. I tried to download some free apps with map feature and encountered the same issue.

If try to compare the map of West Bank on the western side of Dead Sea (
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=31.531726,35.48584&aq=&sll=37.09024,-95.712891&sspn=23.959196,51.943359&safe=on&ie=UTF8&z=11), you can see that the map data on google or the offical maps app provide a lot of detail information. While the map display by MapKit only show the country boundary lines.

Mapkit framework is not showing the Google Map? Or it is a matter of settings? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that because the West Bank is a controversial area, it's probably Google's fault. Google often shows different maps of the same region, depending on which country the HTTP request originated from.

http://www.pcworld.com/article/174205/google_placates_india_china_with_different_map_versions.html

Comment: Thanks Chris. I am accessing the Google map using the same internet connection. The only different is google vs mapkit. If your assumption is correct, I should see the consistent map no matter by which means.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misread your question. What features are missing from the Mobile version of the map that are present in the Full Google Maps? The Mobile version only has a subset of features of the Full Google Maps.

Comment: Hmm...the offical maps app should not built by MapKit. It has streetview and such other features. Thanks Chris.